# Nav bar menu when smaller width

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm working on formatting in my HTML, so when the width of the page is below a certain width, the options in my nav bar wrap, which isn't what I want. I want to hide the options and replace it with one option, 'menu', that will be a drop down list containing all other options. I got the hiding to work but for some reason my 'menu' option doesn't appear. Can someone help me out please

*Disclaimer:* I copied most of the code off w3school

HTML:

```
<nav>
<a title="Go to 'Before Rutherford' page" href="#">BEFORE RUTHERFORD</a>
<a title="Go to 'Experiment + results' page" href="exp.html">EXPERIMENT + RESULTS</a>
<a title="Go to 'What it changed' page" href="chang.html">WHAT IT CHANGED</a>
<a title="Go to 'Scattering equation' page" href="equa.html">SCATTERING EQUATION</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a title="Go to 'Before Rutherford' page" href="#">BEFORE RUTHERFORD</a>
        <a title="Go to 'Experiment + results' page" href="exp.html">EXPERIMENT + RESULTS</a>
        <a title="Go to 'What it changed' page" href="chang.html">WHAT IT CHANGED</a>
        <a title="Go to 'Scattering equation' page" href="equa.html">SCATTERING EQUATION</a>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 25, 50);
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}

nav a {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 192, 0);
}

 @media (max-width: 1045px) { 
    nav a{display: none;} 
   .dropbtn {display:block;}
}

.dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(0, 25, 50);
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(255, 192, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove display:none; from .bropbtn**

Add:

```css
 
@media (min-width: 1045px) { 
   
   .dropbtn {display:none;}
}
```